# Matlab plot labels are redacted by export_fig

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a figure with some translucent (semi-transparent) portion. If I plot the figure using the Matlab `print` function, the translucence does not work. So, I am using `export_fig` for this purpose. However, this redacts the axis labels if these are long, which is the case with my plot. I need to print the figure in `eps` format. Here is my code:

```
clear all;

a = 10;
figure;

fplot(@(x) a*x^2, [-4 4]);
hold on;
ylim([-10 70]);
grid on;

xlabel ( 'This is my greyed out x label (x_1)');
ylabel ( 'This is my greyed out y label (y_1)');

x = [-4 -4 0 0];
y = [-10 70 70 -10];

h = fill(x, y, rgb('green'));
set(h,'facealpha',.5, 'EdgeColor', 'none');

export_fig Fig1.eps;
export_fig Fig1.pdf;

print -depsc Fig2.eps
```

Here is the `Fig1.eps` that I get with `export_fig` function. `Fig1.pdf` is similar.

[image: Figure with export_fig]

And here is the `Fig2.eps` that I get with `print` function.

[image: Figure with print function]

I would appreciate if someone could either help to print the labels correctly with `export_fig` or find an alternate to print translucent figure in `eps` format. I am using Matlab 2014.

Thanks in advance,

A.

Comment: Why eps? Pdf is much better suited for transparency (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/which-figure-type-to-use-pdf-or-eps) and [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28788/what-unique-benefits-does-the-eps-format-provide)).

Comment: @rinkert You may be right. However, I get the same result even if I use `export_fig Fig1.pdf`.

Comment: And with `print -dpdf Fig.pdf`? You may need to adjust the papersize property of the fig. It works for me on 2019a.

Comment: Yes. This works for me too. Thank you.